# Get data from Internet explorer to excel

Tags: html, angularjs, vba, excel

I'm developing a macro to get data from a Internet Explorer Table and load in a sheet in Excel.

With this code I can get the titles of the table but i can't get the content

```
    Sub extraerDatos()

    Dim URL As String
    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument
    Dim TDelements As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim TDelement As HTMLTableCell
    Dim oElement As Object
    Dim r As Long


    URL = "URL"

    Set IE = New InternetExplorer

    With IE
        .Navigate URL
        .Visible = True

        'Cargar pagina
        While .Busy Or .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend

        Set HTMLdoc = .Document
    End With
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))

Set dados = HTMLdoc.getElementsByClassName("tableContainer")
 (0).getElementsByTagName("span")
    I = 0
 For Each oElement In dados
    Sheets("Hoja1").Range("A" & I + 1) = dados(I).innerText
    I = I + 1
 Next oElement
End Sub
```

This is part of the HTML code of the page

```
<div class="tableContainer"  >
        <div class="tlnTable tlnw12" id="tlnAngTableTransfers" style="display:none" >
            <span style="margin:0; padding-bottom: 10px;" class="field-validation-error ng-binding" ng-show="model.bTransferRequired">Select at least one transfer</span>
            <div class="tlnHeader tlnw12"> <!-- HEADER -->
                <div class="tlnw3">
                    <div class="tlnw1 tlntd">
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="model.grid.selected" ng-change="model.grid.selectAll()"/> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="tlnw6 tlntd">
                        <a href="#" class="tlnSortLink tlnw12" ng-click="model.grid.sortableColumns.columns.transferId.changeSort()">
                            <span class="tlnw10">Transfer ID / PO-SO Number </span>
                            <span class="tlnSortIco tlnw2" ng-show="model.grid.sortableColumns.lastSortedColumn.id === model.grid.sortableColumns.columns.transferId.id" >
                                <span class="tlnSortAsc tlnw12 " ng-class="{act: model.grid.sortableColumns.lastSortedColumn.modifier==='asc', inact: model.grid.sortableColumns.lastSortedColumn.modifier==='desc'}" ></span>
                                <span class="tlnSortDesc inact tlnw12" ng-class="{act: model.grid.sortableColumns.lastSortedColumn.modifier==='desc', inact: model.grid.sortableColumns.lastSortedColumn.modifier==='asc'}"></span>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
```

I Understand that the NG tags are the content of the table but I don't know how get it, for my spreadsheet..

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't see where you posted the actual URL, so all I can do is make a generic recommendation, but I can't actually test the script for you.

```
Sub DumpData()

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True

URL = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=sbux&ql=1"

'Wait for site to fully load
IE.Navigate2 URL
Do While IE.Busy = True
   DoEvents
Loop

RowCount = 1

With Sheets("Sheet1")
   .Cells.ClearContents
   RowCount = 1
   For Each itm In IE.document.all
      .Range("A" & RowCount) = itm.tagname
      .Range("B" & RowCount) = itm.ID
      .Range("C" & RowCount) = itm.classname
      .Range("D" & RowCount) = Left(itm.innertext, 1024)

      RowCount = RowCount + 1
   Next itm
End With
End Sub
```

Thanks for the script Joel!!  Based on the results of what you get, can you make the appropriate changes to get the data from the table you are working with?

Comment: Hi Ryguy..Thanks is very interesting because with this macro I get All data of page. But it's posible select specific tags or ID'S for delimited the information of the column D?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Can you post an example.  Also, know that you can test the contents of itm.innertext with an IF...THEN statement.